# Fluent nhibernate BuildSessionFactory with Microsoft.Data.Sqlite is not Working

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, microsoft.data.sqlite

Trying to establish session factory on Microsoft.Data.Sqlite with fluent nhibernate. All references are added and are available in the bin folder on runtime.

```
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqliteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile(DbFilePath))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CheckExe>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

This method throws exception as "The requested collection 'DataTypes' is not defined."

Tried adding the driver and dialect in the configuration NHibernate.Driver.MicrosoftDataSqlClientDriver and NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect both through config xml and through c# code set property . But, facing another blocker error as follows.

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.SetProperty("connection.connection_string", ConnectionString);
cfg.SetProperty("dialect", typeof(global::NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName);
cfg.SetProperty("connection.driver_class", typeof(global::NHibernate.Driver.MicrosoftDataSqlClientDriver).AssemblyQualifiedName);

Fluently.Configure(cfg).Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CheckExe>()).BuildSessionFactory();
```

> Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.MicrosoftDataSqlClientDriver, NHibernate, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.

Tried this way too - resulted in same error

```
return Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqliteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile(DbFilePath).Driver<MicrosoftDataSqlClientDriver>().Dialect<SQLiteDialect>())
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CheckExe>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: The first error indicates some problem with the database file or some support in MicrosoftDataSqlClientDriver is missing. The second error might be some version mismatch. I would try to fix the first error because the first code looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
_sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqliteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c.Is($"data source={_dbFilePath};")).Dialect<NHibernate.Extensions.Sqlite.SqliteDialect>().Driver<NHibernate.Extensions.Sqlite.SqliteDriver>())
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf())
.ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema).BuildSessionFactory();
```

This worked for me and the exception got resolved; however if we try to create the session factory again then another exception occurs:

> ERROR NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - could not complete schema
> update System.ArgumentException: More restrictions were provided than
> the collection 'Tables' supports. at
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.GetSchema(String
> collectionName, String[] restrictionValues) at
> NHibernate.Dialect.Schema.AbstractDataBaseSchema.GetTables(String
> catalog, String schemaPattern, String tableNamePattern, String[]
> types) at
> NHibernate.Dialect.Schema.SQLiteDataBaseMetaData.GetTables(String
> catalog, String schemaPattern, String tableNamePattern, String[]
> types) at
> NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.GetTableMetadata(String name,
> String schema, String catalog, Boolean isQuoted) at
> NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.GenerateSchemaUpdateScript(Dialect
> dialect, IDatabaseMetadata databaseMetadata) at
> NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.Execute(Action`1 scriptAction,
> Boolean doUpdate)

With or without any schema update - this occurs whenever a schema update is called.

Also, the same works fine with `System.Data.Sqlite`, with `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` the exception occurs.